# JQuery validator tooltip, need help identifing javascript library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Hi can anyone identify which javascript library was used to create this validation ui?

[image]

Thanks

EDIT:

I've discovered that this validation is caused by the standard JQuery library by adding required="true" to field names.

I've been debugging in jsfiddle and I've narrowed it down.
See example.

http://jsfiddle.net/WypT8/31/

My main gripe was that I cant get it to work in IE.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It could be any library. The library is not really relevant to the display. Are you trying to track down a certain plugin?

Comment: Yeah, the display seems different to that of usual jquery.validate. The validation is triggered by adding the attribute required="true" rather than class="required" I get a different results depending on which one is used.

Comment: Can't you look in the source to see what the plugin is (*if* it is a plugin)?

Comment: Hi Alex, I've tried that. I've just used jsfiddle to narrow down the problem. It seems that the validation is caused by the standard jquery library if you add the required="true" to a field. The main problem I'm having is that it doesnt seem to work in IE
http://jsfiddle.net/WypT8/31/

Comment: Just marked it as correct, cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Look ma, no JavaScript!

That is actually HTML5; the [`required` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute) is used by the latest HTML5 compliant browsers to validate a form before being submitted.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/yWR4t/).

It doesn't work in IE because IE does not support this feature yet.

Comment: Cheers, You're right, I could of sworn that I removed the jquery library and it stopped working... It looks really cool. I wonder if there is a library that replicates the look and feel of this/

Answer (score 0):

What about the [library detector firefox add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/library-detector/)?